# Can we add webhook url directly inside the pinescript indicator/strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I just created an indicator and also backtested it using strategy tester. Now I wish to run it automated with a 3rd party application. How can i add their webhook url in alert programmatically? any code snippets would be amazing!! I am new to pinescript

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only configure the alert message programmatically not the webhook URL.

Comment: in that case, can i set alert manually and then later trigger them programmatically based on a condition i put in the code (and include a message while triggering)?

Comment: No. As soon as you create an alert, a snapshot of your chart will be saved it will run on the server. Any changes you make after that won't be affecting your existing alert configuration.

Comment: Man!! then how do people do algotrading using the script they built on pinescript? Is there some other piece of puzzle i am missing here?

Comment: Why do you want to add the webhook programmatically? What's the issue with using the alert dialog box?

Comment: because not all brokers are supported by tradingview so in order to send information to another website, I need webhooks. BTW even in tradingview listed brokers (interactive brokers, etc.), how can I execute buy/sell/TP/SL with pinescript?? couldn't figure out where to find guidance for it :((

Comment: I still don't get it. You can place the webhook link via the alert message dialog box. What's the difference if you do it there or via the script? Automated trading is not supported by Tradingview/Pinescript. You can trade manually with the listed ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add url in scrip of tv

if you want to do algo trading there is a way to do it ~>

bro if you have subscription of tv

1st  create broker api and secret key copy it
2nd  paste api and secreat key in 3party application bot then bot give you a url
copy it .

3st  create a alert  based on condition and write messages what you want to send
to bot so he understand it when to buy/sell order
application so that bot can understand
4nd  paste url in alert action menu  in webhook box
5th  As alert triger   send message to bot . bot exicute order on broker or
exchange

if you dont have a subscription plan
it has difficult to do it

there is other way to do it it will different
1st open a website  https://pipedream.com/@/new/build this link create a work flow
in triger use email as a triger copy email
1st create a alert in alert there is a alert  option email to sms click on that
paste here  and verify emai otp send to pipedream workflow `~> body in  text
2nd  click on + button of workflow send http post request and paste bot url there
3rd message send to bot by pipedream and bot will exicute order